# Copying files from Windows PC to Android denied with error message "unsupported file type"

Tags: file-transfer, windows

I bought Moto G6 Plus with Android 8 and I want to restore some files which I backed up from my older phone, Moto G (1st Gen.)

I connect the phone to my Windows PC via a USB cable and enable in the phone: Use USB to Transfer Files. I can send .mp3 files. I cannot send (paste) a .vcf file (my contacts) and .png images (screenshots). The message I get is:

> The `[filename.ext]` file type is not supported on this device. If it is a media file, you may be able to use Windows Media Player to convert the file to a playable type prior to transfer. Do you wish to skip this file now?

And I get Skip/Skip All/Cancel options only.

But I can get any file type from the phone and into my PC which is weird.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this? (preferably without having to install another app).

Comment: On the dialog that appears from Windows, there is no `Yes. Your files will be copied but you might not be able to play or view it on your device.`? If there is click it.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio no there is no such option, I would have clicked it.

Comment: You are using MTP and copying files from PC to phone, and getting the error. Right?

Comment: yes, exactly that's it